# Replacing bathtub with washer / dryer

Tags: plumbing

We're thinking of moving our washer and dryer from a small room off the kitchen, to upstairs in our master bathroom. We have an old tub that's never been used where they'd fit perfectly. I can easily grab the water lines from the tub - but can I tie the washer drain (after the trap) to the bathtub drain? It should already be vented properly, correct?

Comment: If the size(diameter of pipe) is right you should be able to.  I will assume it is a normal size dryer using 240 volts/30 amps, so you will need a new circuit using the breaker in your panel.  A new circuit will mean to go by new code, so it will need a GFCI breaker( if not already).  Highly recommended in a bathroom.

Comment: Please post a photo of the site and the pipes

Comment: Picture of what I’m looking at: https://ibb.co/vc1vNck

Comment: Can I put the standpipe straight into the trap in the floor so it’s lower than the purple section in the picture, so I can reuse the vent and connection to the main?